# Circle estimation from 2D data set

Tags: image-processing, gesture, gesture-recognition, gestures

I am doing some computer vision based hand gesture recognising stuff. Here, I want to detect a circle (a circular motion) made by my hand. My initial stages are working fine and I am able to get a blob whose centroid from each frame I am plotting. This is essentially my data set. A collection of 2D co-ordinate points. Now I want to detect a circular type motion and say generate a call to a function which says "Circle Detected". The circle detector will give a YES / NO boolean output.
Here is a sample of the data set I am generating in 40 frames[image: The x, y values are just plotted to a bitmap image using MATLAB]

The x, y values are just plotted to a bitmap image using MATLAB.
My initial hand movement was slow and later I picked up speed to complete the circle within stipulated time (40 frames). There is no hard and fast rule about the number of frames thing but for now I am using a 40 frame sliding window for circle detection (0-39) then (1-40) then (2-41) etc.
I am also calculating the arc-tangent between successive points using:

```
angle = atan2(prev_y - y, prev_x - x) * 180 / pi;
```

Now what approach should I take for detecting a circle (This sample image should result in a YES). The angle as I am noticing is not steadily increasing from 0 to 360. It does increase but with jumps here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in full or nearly full circles:

I think that the standard parameter estimation approach: Hough/RANSAC won't work very well in this case.

Since you have frames order and therefore distances between consecutive blob centers, you can create a nearly uniform sub sample of the data (let say, pick 20 points spaced ~evenly), calculate the center and measure the distance of all points from that center.

If it is nearly a circle all points will have similar distance from the center.

If you want to do something slightly more robust, you can:

- Compute center (mean) of all points.
- Perform gradient descent to update the center: should be fairly easy an you won't have local minima. The error term I would probably use is `max(D) - min(D)` where `D` is the vector of distances between the blob centers and estimated circle center (but you can use robust statistics instead of max & min)
- Evaluate the circle

Comment: Yes I already tried Hough transform but its not working.. I will be trying out your first method first now. Thanks..

Comment: No problem, I am quite sure the simple approach will work as long as you have most of the circle and you manage to sample the blob centers more or less evenly.

Comment: Okay I tried the first approach. The speed of my hand movement has to be more or less uniform otherwise the centroid shift towards the slowly drawn points(more dense area). I was thinking maybe drawing a line between the points and then estimate the center. But this will be computationally expensive.

Comment: I don't think the speed really has to be uniform, you can sub-sample the blob centers. For example if the max distance between two centers is X pixels, take only samples that are ~X pixels apart, I don't think it should be very accurate since you are only trying to estimate the center of the circle and it should be quite robust

Comment: With some fine tunings and the sub-sampling, I am pretty much getting good results.. thank you :) I will try out the gradient descent later when I get time.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked. If you're using the gradient descent approach you can actually use sum(d^2) as an error function where d is the distance between the a point and the estimated center.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Least Square estimation. Numerically you can use the Nelder-Mead method. You get the circle that best approximate your points and on the basis of the residual error value you decide whether to consider the circle valid or not.

Being points the array of the points, xc, yc the coordinates of the center and r the radius, this could be an example of error to minimize:

```
class Circle
{
    private PointF[] _points;
    public Circle(PointF[] points)
    {
        _points = points;
    }
    public double MinimizeFunction(double xc, double yc, double r)
    {
        double d, d2, dx, dy, sum;

        sum = 0;
        foreach(PointF p in _points)
        {
            dx = p.X - xc;
            dy = p.Y - yc;
            d2 = dx * dx + dy * dy;
            // sum += d2 - r * r;
            d = Math.Sqrt(d2) - r;
            sum += d * d;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public double ResidualError(double xc, double yc, double r)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(MinimizeFunctional(xc, yc, r)) / (_points.Length - 3);
    }

}
```

There is a slight difference between the commented functional and the uncommented, but for practical reason this difference is meaningless. Instead, from a theoretical point of view the difference is important.

Since you need to supply a initial values set (xc, yc, r), you can calculate the circle given three points, choosing three points far from each other.

If you need more details on "circle given three points" or Nelder-Mead you can google or ask me here.